# Remove attribute from configurable selection without recreating all child products

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

My client has a lot of products that I imported via CSV in their website.

Many configurable products have this problem:

- The configurable product has n virtual products;
- the virtual products are selectable via some attributes (let's say color, size, shape);
- in some cases all the virtual products of a configurable have all the same color;
- the client wants to remove that attribute from the selection.

I explain it better: He wants that the client from the ecommerce will not have to select that attribute (color, in this example) anymore for that configurable, but only shape and size.

So the attribute has to be removed only from the selectable attributes in the ecommerce product page. It should remain in the attribute set (many other products use it) and in the virtual products of the configurable mentioned before.

It happens often and with many products so it should be something that the client can do autonomously from the backoffice.

If he does it by clicking `Edit Configurations` in the configurable product page in the backoffice, it re-generates all the child products but I would like it to keep them, since they were imported with specific SKUs and they should be mantained.

Does anybody have an idea how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The only workaround to do this mantaining the old virtual products is:

- click on `Edit Configurations`;
- select the attributes I want to be selectable on the product page on the ecommerce;
- select only one value per attribute;
- create the configurations (it will be only a product;
- remove it from the list;
- click on `Add Products Manually`;
- add the previous virtual products;
- save the configurable product.